# Unable to open .pdf file in the application

Tags: android, pdf

I am try to display a .pdf document in my application. I am unable to display it. I am getting invalid document path error with adobe reader and pdf viewer display file cannot be opened. Please any one of you let me know what mistake am I doing here. If there is a better way in achieving this please teach me. I have posted the code which I am using:

```
public class HelpScreen extends ActionBarActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_help_screen);

        // Initializing, setting text and color of tool bar
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        CopyReadAssets();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_help_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private void CopyReadAssets()
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        Log.d("Pana", "The value of assests is " +assetManager);

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "help_document_task_management_system_document_4.pdf");
        try
        {
            in = assetManager.open("help_document_task_management_system_document_4.pdf");
            out = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            copyFile(in, out);
            in.close();
            in = null;
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(
                Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/" + "/help_document_task_management_system_document_4.pdf"),
                "application/pdf");


        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
}
```

EDITED CODE:

```
public class HelpScreen extends ActionBarActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_help_screen);

        // Initializing, setting text and color of tool bar
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        CopyReadAssets();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_help_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private void CopyReadAssets() {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        Log.d("Pana", "The value of assests is " + assetManager);

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "help_document_task_management_system_document_4.pdf");
        // File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "help_document_task_management_system_document_4.pdf");
        try {
            in = assetManager.open("help_document_task_management_system_document_4.pdf");
            out = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            copyFile(in, out);
            in.close();
            in = null;
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(
                Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know my mistake and help me come out of this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What string do you get from Uri.parse ?

Comment: @Thealon: The value of the string which I get is : Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///data/data/com.ms.t.tms/files/help_document_task_management_system_document_4.pdf typ=application/pdf }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Third party apps have no rights to access that file. Use `FileProvider` to serve it, or copy the file to [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) instead of [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Comment: As you said, I am using Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) in my file statement, can you please let me know what should I do in Uri.Parse line for getting this file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Keshav1234: Do not use `Uri.parse()`. Use `Uri.fromFile()`, passing in the same `File` object that you used to download the file.

Comment: I did that, I am getting an error stating file cannot be accessed, I have updated the changed code, Can you please have  look and please let me know what should I change? My pdf file is in assets folder. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Keshav1234: You are still writing the file to internal storage. Remove the call to `openFileOutput()` and use standard Java file I/O to create a `FileOutputStream` on your `File`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally file got opened. I forgot to use FileOutputStream. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have two `/` in your file path after `getFilesDir()` in your intent creation.